# How to store database credentials for an open-source Heroku Node.js app?

Tags: node.js, heroku, github, environment-variables, cloud9-ide

I am building a Node.js application and need to store database credentials (and other runtime properties) in such a way that they can be read when deployed on Heroku. My source is available in a public GitHub repository.

I am currently using environment variables, configured using `heroku config:add`, but am looking to understand if there are any alternatives. I would potentially like to use [Cloud9 IDE](http://c9.io/), but it does not currently support environment variables.

Another option is to store the parameters in a config. file, but I believe the file would need to be checked in to Git (and as such, be publicly available) in order to be pushed to Heroku.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ENV vars are generally considered the way to go, and the way Heroku do it themselves for database_urls and the like.

As you and your app are the only people with access to the env vars, you're generally OK security wise.

Putting credentials in Git or similar is a bad idea as it's another place that needs to be secured.

Comment: This makes sense. I am simply looking to understand the available alternatives, as I can't set environment variables in Cloud9 IDE.

Comment: I'm not clear on what choice of code editor has to do with this problem?

Comment: I know that environment variables are one way (seemingly the best) of accomplishing my goal. I am looking to see what other solutions exist since I can't use environment variables and Cloud9 IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The one way I know of to solve the problem for development using command-line arguments. These can be specified in your run/debug configuration. You can then access the parameters in process.argv. Of course this means that they will be stored in your Cloud9IDE dev environment. You could then use the ENV variables in a retail production. This will at least prevent the credentials from being visible in source or config files.